# Generic casting type isn't enough to retrieve "new" property correctly

Tags: c#, generics, casting

#### I have one pain to solved in generic type.

To unit-test, I have one fake ScriptManager type, defined alike this:

```
public class FakeScriptManager : ScriptManager
{
   public new virtual bool IsNavigating { get; private set; }
}
```

My tested method looks like this:

```
    public string GetHistoryPoint<TScriptManager>(string key, TScriptManager scriptManager)
            where TScriptManager : ScriptManager
{
          TScriptManager realScriptManager = Convert.ChangeType(scriptManager, scriptManager.GetType());
          if (realScriptManager.IsNavigating)
          {
              // Do something
          }
}
```

Testing method looks like:

```
using (FakeScriptManager scriptManager = new FakeScriptManager(true, false))
{
    object value = _handler.GetHistoryPoint(keyExists, scriptManager);
}
```

I intend to set the **NEW** property **IsNavigating** is **true** for FakeScriptManager variable. But it's unable. Variable realScriptManager seems incapable casted from the expected generic TScriptManager type.

***Note:***
Debugging, trying to cast directly input parameter scriptManager with concrete type FakeScriptManager, it's ok.

So, my problem is: **How to make the generic-typed GetHistoryPoint method work properly as my expectation?**
Any one give me one helping hand please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In almost all cases, method hiding (`new`) is the wrong thing to do; a better approach would be `override` in **almost every case**. My main answer here would be: remove the `new`.

The compiler is doing the right thing; it only knows about `IsNavigating` via `TScriptManager : ScriptManager`, so it  should not be a surprise that it uses that one. C# generics are not like C++ templates; they can use polymorphism etc from the known (`where`) structure of the type, and **do not** look for the best fit on the actual `T` on a name only basis (duck-typing).

If you really **need** this, then either reflection, or, in 4.0, `dynamic` (which is fully duck-typed):

```
dynamic obj = scriptManager;
if((bool)obj.IsNavigating) {
       ...
}
```

(note the above may fail for "explicit interface implementation", but that isn't what you are doing)

The `Convert.ChangeType` here does nothing useful.

Comment: Thanks Marc,
The cycling problem is that being-tested method belongs to a Common lib in framework 3.5. :( I'm not authorized to make it evolve as many sites running through the library is currently below 4.0.
Anyway, thanks for your explanation and approach with dynamic type.

Comment: @UndefinedIdentity then use reflection; presumably `if((bool)typeof(TScriptManager).GetProperty("IsNavigating").GetValue(scriptManager, null)) {...}`